# Restrict users from putting the close date in the past, except for specific users

Tags: salesforce

Trying to edit this validation rule which restricts users from updating opportunities (all open opps) if the close date is in the past, however, the user role mentioned doesn't seem to work. I'd like to allow just two users to be able to put a past close date if need be.

AND ( 
NOT ( CONTAINS( $UserRole.Name, "Manager")), 
ISCHANGED( CloseDate ) , 
CloseDate < Today() 
)

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem as well using CONTAINS with $UserRole.Name (or $UserRole.Anything really).  Maybe CONTAINS only likes to work on columns that are in the database, I'm not sure.  I would note though that it works fine if you use =, like $UserRole.Name="Line Manager".  That's not ideal, but would it be a valid workaround for you?

Comment: There's also a bizarre property of CONTAINS that's in the Salesforce.com docs: "When using this function in a validation rule or workflow rule, fields that are blank are considered valid. For example, if you have a validation rule that tests to see if the serial number of an asset contains “A,” all assets that have a blank serial number are considered valid."  So if you're testing with a user that has no role specified (so role name is blank), that could confound you also.